# Error 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)) in connect

Tags: mysql, database

Hi guys i am getting this error

> Error 1045 (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)

In connect when i join my arma 2 epoch server i changed the file login requirements thing and database log in to match each other but still get this error.

Comment: so which error is it, the pink/peach error or the error in your Title. I could walk you through it but you would **need** to follow the steps I typed up yesterday [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32288517/1816093) and create pastie.org output for each step. And ultimately connect with a password, not a non password. If you are up for it, then create the detailed pastie, otherwise, wait for someone else